# How to use my own video and be able to play from a specific time?

Tags: 7

I have Drupal 7 with the video module installed using ffmpeg. The video is playing fine. However, I noticed that users can only play from the beginning of the video. I would like to have users play from any specific time.

The embed video field module is only for embedding other videos so does not suit my needs.

Answer (score 0):

May be you can try with javascript

```
document.getElementById('YOURVIDEOID').addEventListener('loadedmetadata', function() {
  this.currentTime = 50;
}, false);
```

In jquery

```
var vid = $("#video")[0];
$("#button").click(function(){
    skipTime(100);
});

function skipTime(time) {
    vid.play();
    vid.pause();
    vid.currentTime = time;
    vid.play();
};
```

Comment: How do I add listener to the clicked event and get the selected time from my video?